# Appropriate way of dynamically adding instances of TextView and Button

Tags: android, android-layout, instance, android-tablelayout

I'm building an application for a university project - It's a random word/ brainstorming generator. I have an `Activity` which retrieves a random word from my `SQLiteDatabase` and puts it in a `TextView`. Next to the `TextView` is a `Button` which acts as a 'hold' `Button`(like a fruit-machine). Something like this:

[image]

At the moment I'm dynamically adding/removing a new `TextView`/`Button` and adding it to a row in a *TableLayout*, I really want to use a **new instance** (sorry, coming from a AS3 background) of **the same `TextView`/`Button`** (so they do the same thing).  This is what I'm getting so far:

[image]

My question(s) is really, is this possible? Or what would be the best approach for something of this nature. Is is a `TableLayout` even the right thing to use?

If It helps in your advise giving:

- I want to be able to save/share a users 'session' at some point.
- possibly give the user the option to adjust number of text fields they can add (currently I've limited them to 5)

**Edit:**  Also I think what I'm getting muddled-up with is, If I add a new text/button - what would be the best way of setting it so they all do the same thing. With XML I can use their ID, is that still possible 'programatically'?

Comment: If your choices are limited (probably under 10-20), it's ok to create them in this way. Otherwise, I would suggest using a ListView and each item is a RelativeLayout. 
Saving ain't a problem. Use SharedPreferences would be the easiest without touching sql statements.

Comment: Like Xandy said, you can add Views dynamically in a ListView and it will stretch.  If you don't want to use a ListView, you can put the TextView on the layout and put their visibility to "GONE", which will draw the layout like if they were not there.  When you change their visibility to "INVISIBLE", they will take their place on the layout but will not appear (thus the neighbour Views will be scaled).  When you change the visibility to "VISIBLE", they, of course, appear.

For adding new instances of View, I think that you can't do it once you called setContentView();.

Comment: I just have a vague memory of trying to add a new instance to a layout and having an error because I had already used setContentView().  If that's the case, you could simply load a list of View that are set to "GONE" by default, but inflated with setContentView().  If nobody has answered more properly tomorrow, I'll come back to try it and write a proper/complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, Also I think what I'm getting muddled-up with is, If I add a new text/button - what would be the best way of setting it so they all do the same thing. With XML I can use their ID, is that still possible 'programatically'?

Comment: If you do programatically, just keep a reference in a ArrayList to those TextViews, no need to use the IDs.

Comment: If you want to add them programatically, you could make a factory that creates new instances that all share the same parameters.  Basically, every parameters accessible from the XML is accessible from Java using very similar names.  The TextView for instance : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

See the XML Attributes table, which shows their related method.

Comment: Programatically you have the method `setId()` to set unique ids to identify the added `TextViews`/`Buttons`. Also if you want to do **the exact same thing no matter what `Button` was clicked** then you could make a layout file(with a `TextView` and a `Button`) to be inflated for the new "rows" and use the `onClick` xml attribute for the Button in that layout file pointing to the same callback method.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I shall have a play-around and come back with what worked.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to get my "add new instances" of text/button working by inflating each `TableRow` holding reference to a TextView/ToggleButton and using addView() to appended it to the `TableLayout`(similar to Luksprog's suggestion). Then in another function which I called getRandomWords() I loop through the table and get a new word for each row. I then do something similar for the buttons to see which have been checked and if true I ignore the row they're in. I'm not sure if it's best practice but it works. I'll try post full code when assignment is marked.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, will edit to answer more completely later.

You can save your state using something simple like this (point to remember is that you can't save anything related to the GUI, so if you want to save the text in a TextView, you must first extract it as a String and then save the String, not the View). EDIT : using this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState

```
 private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
 private int mCurViewMode;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences();
     mCurViewMode = mPrefs.getInt("view_mode", DAY_VIEW_MODE);
 }

 protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();

     SharedPreferences.Editor ed = mPrefs.edit();
     ed.putInt("view_mode", mCurViewMode);
     ed.commit();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Antonie G, I wasn't sure what onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() was or when to use it so I went on [Android dev](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) 
It says:  _This method is deprecated. Use the new Fragment API setRetainInstance(boolean) instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package._